# if/else or double if?

Tags: language-agnostic, if-statement

Are there any difference between using double (or triple,..)if instead of if/else branch, like

```
if(a==b)
{}
else if(a==c)
{}
else if(a==d)
{}
```

---

```
if(a==b)
{}
if(a==c)
{}
if(a==d)
{}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this case

```
if ( conditional ) {
    //do stuff
}
else if ( conditional {
    //do stuff
} ...
```

The system checks conditionals until it find a true value and then it does stuff.

In this case:

```
if ( conditional ) {
    //do stuff
}
if ( conditional ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

The system checks every conditional every time.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a difference. In the first case the evaluation will stop if one of the conditions is satisfied and others won't be evaluated whereas in the second case all conditions will be evaluated no matter if one is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

The second one will check all the conditions and if `a`, `c` and `d` were equal, for example, then both `if(a==c) {}` and `if(a==d) {}` would execute.

The first one would break away from the other checks once one of the condition is met.